# LLVM Check if a PointerType is a Const pointer

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I Need to Know, if the a given LLVM Type of a function argument is actually a const pointer.

Is there a way to check this in LLVM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is probably [LLVM's function](https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#function-attributes) and [function parameter attributes](https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#parameter-attributes). Here, for example, is check to see whether a called function's return value can ever be null:

```
foo = called->hasAttribute(AttributeList::ReturnIndex, llvm::Attribute::NonNull)
```

This checks whether a particular value is a const argument

```
isa<Argument>(value) && cast<Argument>(value)->onlyReadsMemory()
```

Well, assuming that I know what you mean by const pointer. Constness has so many shades of meaning...

Comment: This Works somehow I think. But do you know why some function parameters (get them with getArgOperand from an CallInst) are not an "Argument"?

Comment: Because there's no particular reason for them to be. In C code such as `extern int a(int, int); int b(int c) { return a(c, 42};` the `CallInst` in the compiled code for `b` will contain one `Argument` and one `ConstantInt`, because the first argument was a parameter to `b()`. If you want to learn about the attributes of `a` you have to call `hasAttribute()` on it, not on the `CallInst`. The `CallInst`'s attributes relate to the call, not to the function called.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!